# Chat room name suggestions for general discussion

Tags: discussion, chat

When I have the main site open in one tab and the general discussion chat open in another. I can't tell them apart from the browser tab title.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, I can't tell the chat from the main site.

[As suggested here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246289/132547) changing the name of the chat room would solve this problem.

I have changed the name to general discussion for now as you can see at least now I can tell them apart.

[image]

However I would like a better name. I thought about the water cooler or something similar but I would like something car related.

So post one suggestion per answer and why you think it's the best. It's okay if you have more than one, just post as separate answers so we can vote on each one individually.

It would be great if the name was enough for you to know it's for general discussion but ultimately the chat room has a description that tells you that.

Comment: Where do mechanics hang out and chat during breaks?

Comment: @endolith ... They don't take breaks if they want to make money :D

Comment: When are we going to make the change? Give us something!! Also, since M&TV just gained full SE status (out of Beta), when is Mechanics going to go over?? Get 'er Done!

Answer (score 6):

My suggestion:  **Under the Hood**

Perhaps a little obvious, but it's all I've got for now.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion, too, is a little obvious, but viable (if not cliche): **The Grease Pit**

Comment: Or (semi) related : **The Pitstop**

Comment: @Zaid ... OOooo ... I like that too :D Could also be just **Pitstop**.

Answer (score 2):

**The Pitstop**

Paulster2 suggested it again [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20603031#20603031)

It's got three upvotes to the comment on [this answer](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/310/85)

So for now it's **The Pitstop**, this isn't necessarily final, if I get feedback otherwise.